# PHP Remove email addresses from comma separated string

Tags: php, email, remove-if

I'm trying to delete the email from a comma separated string. I have a script that brings me emails.  Any way to do this quickly:

```
$cadena = "Example1@email.com,0001,00005,0010,Example3@email2.com,003";

$cadena = explode(",", $cadena);        

foreach($cadena as $res){
    if(filter_var($res, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $result[] = $res;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array(Example1@email.com,Example3@email2.com);
```

But I need:

```
string "0001,00005,0010,003"
```

Comment: Uhhh... `!filter_var($res, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: invert conditiion - `if( ! filter_var($res, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding to your result array if it DOES validate as an email, so change it to add if it DOES NOT `!` validate:

```
$cadena = explode(",", $cadena);        

foreach($cadena as $res){
    if(!filter_var($res, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $result[] = $res;
    }
}
```

Then just `implode()` it:

```
$result = implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can count on all the other stuff in the string being like it is in your example, instead of trying to find and remove emails, you can filter it with `is_numeric`.

```
$result = implode(',', array_filter(explode(',', $cadena), 'is_numeric'));
```

If the values you want to keep just happen to be numeric in your example, never mind.